# Product of random variables greater than dependent sum of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, upper-lower-bounds

Let $X := {1\dots m}$ be the set of indexes corresponding to the elements of the vector of i.i.d. random variables $w:=(w_1, \dots, w_m)$. Let there be the subsets $Y, Z \subseteq X$ which may or may not overlap.

I am trying to obtain a lower bound on the expression

$\mathbb{P}\left(|\prod_{i \in Y} w_i|\geq 1 + |\sum_{i \in Z}w_i)|\right)$.

For example, for random variables $w:=(a, b, c)$, I would be interested e.g. in a lower bound for

$\mathbb{P}(|ab| \geq 1 + |b+c|)$.

Perhaps there is a concentration inequality, transformation, etc. that applies to this case?

Comment: Your **expression** and your **for example** don't quite match up -- did you mean for your **for example** to be $|ab| \geq 1 + |b + c|$?

Comment: exactly, just fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: This is an interesting question. I suppose such a bound (if it exists) would need to depend on the support of the variables; for instance, if your variables are supported on $[0, 1]$, then the probability of this happening is $0$, so your bound would need to be trivial.

Comment: Agreed, and that would probably include the degree of symmetry around zero (with complete symmetry perhaps being the worst case due to cancellations in the sum).